# 'app-deploy' job needs 'app-verify' job but 'app-verify' is not in any previous stage You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint

Tags: gitlab-ci

Seeing Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:
'app-deploy' job needs 'app-verify' job
but 'app-verify' is not in any previous stage
You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint

Where as both stages are defined

Cache set as below

```
  cache:
    key: ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$CONTEXT/
```

Stages defined as below, snippets

```
app-build:
  stage: build
  # Extending the maven-build function from maven.yaml
  extends: .maven-build
```

```
app-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  extends: .docker-publish
  cache:
    key: ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$CONTEXT/
  variables:
    DOCKERFILE: Dockerfile
    CONTEXT: app
    OUTPUT: app.war
  needs:
    - app-build
    - app-verify
  dependencies:
    - app-build
    - app-verify
```

How to resolve the above error.

Error should go away and no error in pipeline run.

Comment: Your CI file is incomplete, so I can only offer generic advice. You have to make sure that when you have multiple `stage`s, and job B relies on job A, job A **cannot** be part of a later stage.

Answer (score 2):

If both jobs `app-build` and `app-verify` have the same rules as `app-deploy`, then it will work.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. The error message confuses due the "previous". Due to different rules there are cases where a job actually is not in any stage at all.